# Python - transform a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

I have a list like:

```
[['22', '14']]
```

How can I transform it to:

```
[22, 14]
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
L = [['22', '14']]
M = [ int(i) for i in L[0] ]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
a = [['22','14']]
map(int, a[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> lis=[['22', '14']]
>>> map(int,sum(lis,[]))
[22, 14]
```